# swift Ekevents to 2 dimensional array sorted by Date

Tags: swift

I have an array with events which are sorted by date. I want a separate section for each day [monday], [tuesday], ....
How do I create a 2-dimensional array that looks like this?
And how do i get each event in the appropriate section?

> ```
>  [
> [monday]
> [tuesday]
> [wednesday] 
> . .and so on ]
> ```

```
func getEvents(){
        
        let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
        
        for calendar in calendars {
            //            if calendar.title == "Arbeit" {
            
            let anfang = NSDate()
            let ende = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: anfang as Date)!
            let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: anfang as Date, end: ende as Date, calendars: [calendar])
            
            let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
            
            var found:Bool = false
            for event in events {
                if (allEvents.count == 0)
                {
                    allEvents.append(event)
                }
                if (allEvents.count > 0)
                {
                    found = false
                    if ( event.title == allEvents[allEvents.count-1].title  && event.startDate == allEvents[allEvents.count-1].startDate)
                    {
                        found = true
                    }
                }
                if(!found)
                {
                    allEvents.append(event)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution first groups the events based start date by weekday in a dictionary and then transforms the dictionary to a 2D array sorted with todays day first

First set up a Calendar and DateFormatter to use

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.locale = locale
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = locale
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
```

Group the events

```
let byWeekday = Dictionary(grouping: events, by: { formatter.string(from: $0.startDate) })
```

Get the weekdays in the right order

```
let weekdays = calendar.weekdaySymbols
let todayIndex = weekdays.firstIndex(of: formatter.string(from: Date())) ?? calendar.weekdaySymbols.startIndex
let sortedWeekdays = weekdays[todayIndex..<weekdays.endIndex] + weekdays[weekdays.startIndex..<todayIndex]
```

and then create and fill the array

```
var eventsByDay = [[EKEvent]]()

for day in sortedWeekdays {
    eventsByDay.append(byWeekday[day] ?? [])
}
```

Comment: How would i use     text = [yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];     with my 2 D Array